# angular filter in ng-repeat with <=

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using angular and ng-repeat to iterate over data.  I want to show only items where purchased-used <=5, but it is showing 5, 4, 55, 3, 33, 2, etc., as the result set where it should only show 5,4,3,2.

```
 $scope.users = [{
      first_name: 'Richard',
      last_name: 'Grayson',
      purchased: 50,
      used: 10,
    },
    {
      first_name: 'Donna',
      last_name: 'Troy',
      purchased: 6,
      used: 3,
    }]
```

And then on the page:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:user.purchased-user.used<=5:true">
```

Dick should not show in the list, but Donna should.  They both show up though.

I know I could write a function for the filter, but this seems like such a simple comparison that I shouldn't have to.  It seems like it should work, but there's something I'm missing.

Thanks!

Comment: Simple enough to create a custom filter

Comment: Just because you feel like it should isn't sufficient justification FOR it to work, else it wouldn't be necessary for custom filters in the first place.  Remember, angular expressions are NOT full-blown JavaScript, they're just small snippets that the compiler can use to render the appropriate template.  A custom filter is the correct solution here.

Comment: You may want to be careful when wording your question to avoid it turning into a "rant in disguise".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to make a custom filter:

```
$scope.customFilter = function(user){
    return user.purchased-user.used <= 5;
};
```

And call it from your repeater:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter: customFilter">
```